# PDF interaction with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, flash

ok i have a pdf file that is a map of stars.. and next to the stars is the star name in text.... now i can open this pdf in a viewer and do a search for a name and it brings me to the star i was looking for.... so what i want to do is have the same thing happen in jQuery and PHP... i want someone to select from a drop down the star they want and have flash zoom in on the area of the star... is this possible with jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

You can't interact with the PDF Viewing plugin, as it's a security risk. The plugin runs outside of the browser and only renders the PDF into the little frame.

I'd recommend making a HTML document out of the PDF and working with that.